# Problem playing a fetched webm video via Javascript (VP9 Codec) on safari

Tags: javascript, html5-video, fetch-api, webm

I hope you are doing fine today, I am definitely not.

Okay so here is the thing : A client asked me to play a background video on a website, and it happens to be quite huge (56mb in mp4).
Of course, this background video is the most important thing of that website, so I have to fetch it in advance (with the user consent, of course), and once it is fetched, I "reveal" the website.

When I fetch the mp4 file, there is absolutely no problem on any device.

Now, I decided to convert the mp4 file to webm using ffmpeg so that it becomes 'lighter' (11mb). That worked. But, even using VP9 codec, there still is a problem with safari and I am pulling my hair out.

```
let video = {
  url: './assets/video.webm',
  type: 'webm'
}

const fetchAssets = async () => {
  const backgroundVideo = await fetch(video.url)
  const blob = await backgroundVideo.blob()
  const src = await URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const source = document.createElement('source')
  source.type = `video/${video.type}`
  source.src = src
  document.querySelector('.background video').appendChild(source)
}
```

Here is the HTML if it is of any matter

```
<div class="background">
  <video autoplay muted playsinline onplaying="this.controls = false" loop>
  </video>
</div>
```

[chrome results (macOS Monterrey 12.4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEge7.jpg)

[safari results (macOS Monterrey 12.4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jsQa.png)

I thank you in advance for any lead you may have, any idea of where this could come from.

Have a nice day/evening !

Comment: Hello again ! 
I thought it might be from misinterpreted MIME type so I checked, here is the return from a `console.log(blob)`:  
`Blob {
  size: 11113169, 
  type: 'video/webm'
}`

I also thought it might be from misinterpreted codecs, so I created a new Blob, specifying the codecs (and used that new Blob)
`const blob2 = new Blob([blob], { type='video/webm; codecs="vp9", }) // I also tried with vp8`

And, as I am still here, it did not work :/
Have a nice day !

Comment: I suspect your 56 mb MP4 file contains H.264 codec. Try re-encoding as an MP4 (or an MOV) container that has **H.265** for video codec. That should play in Safari. The H.265 codec is closer to VP9 for compression sizes (depends on quality settings used in encoder). To play in Safari means... Use an If/Else statement to check if `canPlay` on the MOV, if not then assume WebM is supported and play that one instead.

Comment: Great idea, I managed to reduce its size to 23.6mb using *H.265* encoding, which is a tad more acceptable !
However, the main problem has not been solved and apart from delivering a product to the client, I truly wonder why I cannot use a fetched webm on Safari !

Thanks a lot though, great workaround !
Have an amazing day sir/madam

Comment: You will have to investigate. I'm not familiar enough with VP9 settings to know if Safari has a problem with your specific file as a Blob object. Does it work if file path is directly provided as `src`? Anyways a second note is that Apple is an MPEG licensor and contributor so its first choice is always MPEG video/audio and generally it does not have to like or support the codecs from rivals like Google's own WebM or Mozilla's own OGV formats.

Comment: @VC.One Yes, if the provided path is directly in src, there is absolutely no problem playing it. That is why I find it weird.